# What is props in class App

Tags: react-native

Can someone explain what is props ?
I always read props is atribute our component, but this is without sense, we using method on this props instead of pass them as an argument.

```
class App extends Component {

    placeDeletedHandler = () => {
        this.props.onDeletePlace();
    };
```

...

Answer (score 4):

You can see props as some parameters you pass to the constructor of your class (which is actually the case). The thing is that those props are not mutable, so they are like read-only properties of your class.

Answer (score 2):

Props are the property such as attributes in HTML tags.  when we want to pass data to component we can use props.
Lets say you want to pass the name to child component then you can pass like this e.g

```
<Component data={name}  />
```

and in this component file you can get it like this e.g

```
    class App extends Component {

     componentDidMount() // or any other function,render,constructor 
      {
        let name=this.props.data
      }

    }
```

**and you can not change the props value in receiving component **
    let me know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain, but I work with React, React-Native for only 3 months, so it can be wrong/imperfect (and despite my very perfectible english).
Props is used when you have to pass something from a parent component to his child component. You can pass states, functions...

```
class ParentComponent extend React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: 'something'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildComponent
                yourprop={this.state.data}
            />
        );
    }
}


class ChildComponent extend React.Component {
    render() {
        /*you can destructure your prop here*/
        const {
            yourprop;
        } = this.props;
        return() {
            <Text>{yourprop}</Text>
        }
    }
}

//or with functional component

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    const {
        yourprop
    } = props

    return (
        <Text>{yourprop}</Text>
    );
};
```

Note if you want to handle the parent state value in children, you have to pass a function in addition.